# How to write query for a condition on join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, orm, relational-database

I am trying to write a query using Rails ORM. Suppose there are two models.

```
class College

has_many :students
```

```
class Student

belongs_to :college
```

The `Student` table has a column named `result` which can either be `pass` or `fail`
Now, I want to get the list of only those colleges where all students have `passed`.

I tried the following

```
College.join(:students).group('colleges.id, students.results').select('colleges.id, count(students) as students_count').where(students: {result: 'pass'}).having('count(*) = students_count')
```

But I am getting this error:
`Caused by PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "students_count" does not exist`

Comment: There's only one question here @philipxy

Comment: There is no question in the body, and the question in the title is about your goal but the erroneous code in the body suggests you are trying to ask about the code & error which as I just commented is not relevant to the question in the title, so it's not clear what you are trying to ask, per my comment. PS Please don't put something only in the title.

Comment: @philipxy I'm not the OP btw... It doesn't have to be a literal question, the problem/request is very clear: "I want to get the list of only those colleges where all students have passed." If your issue is the title then suggest an edit, or at least provide a CONCISE comment about the title.

Comment: @smathy Your last comment is already addressed by my comments & like your 1st comment & ignores the issues they describe & a statement of some wants is not a question. I'm done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best way to do this is as a negative subquery:

```rb
College.where.not(id: Student.select(:college_id).where(result: "fail"))
```

Comment: Should probably use distinct

Comment: Thanks @DeepakMahakale. That looks simple. Do you know if it fires separate query for `select` and `where`?

Comment: Not for the select and where of the `student` query. But it would fire a separate query for the `college` query

Comment: Not true, this runs as a subquery. And no @DeepakMahakale, the distinct is not required, `SELECT * FROM table WHERE id in (1, 1)` only returns one record in SQL.

Comment: You are correct. It is running subquery +1